# three partial derivatives

Tags: calculus

I am having a hard time doing this calculus problem. I have done two assignments on this part of partial derivatives, and I have not had trouble until doing this problem. I just cannot seem to get this one done at all. I do not know what it is.

Find the second partial derivatives for the given function.
$$f(x,y)=\frac{x\ln(2xy)}{5y}$$

I need to find $f_{xx}$, $f_{xy}$ and $f_{yy}$. I just cannot seem to get any of them right. Can someone walk me through each of these so I can see where I am going wrong? Because I am sure I am missing something in my calculation.

Comment: [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a Mathjax basic tutorial. Please, consider writing your questions using this tutorial. Where do you think you are doing wrong? Show us where you stopped so we may help you.

Comment: Is the function $$f(x,y)=\frac{x\ln(2xy)}{5}\cdot y$$ or $$f(x,y) = \frac{x\ln(2xy)}{5y}$$? What are you attempts and efforts, how do your "wrong" derivates look like?

Comment: Do you know what a partial derivative is? And do you know the chain rule, product rule and quotient rule? If not, look them up, that might help for starters.

Comment: Please show any effort. The minimum effort is to react on the comments.

Comment: We really want to see what is precisely unclear. Is it the definition of a partial derivitive? I mean, we could do the calculations for you but that wouldn't be very useful, especially if this is an attempt to avoid doing the calculations yourself.

Comment: Request for help is mostly successful when you mention how you went wrong.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\ \frac{x\ ln(2xy)}{5y} \overset{(*)}{=} \frac{1}{5y} \left( ln(2xy) + x\ \frac{1}{2xy}\ 2y \right) = \frac{1}{5y} \left( ln(2xy) + 1 \right) \\
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}\ \frac{1}{5y} ( ln(2xy) + 1) = \frac{1}{5y} \left(\frac{1}{2xy}\ 2y + 0\right)= \frac{1}{5xy}
$$
$(*)$ Factoring out the constant term $\frac{1}{5y}$. Then applying the product rule with one function being $x$ and the other being $ln(2xy)$. Then the chain rule for the second term of the product rule, the $2y$ term being the "inner derivative" due to the chain rule.

The second derivative is even easier and based exactly on the same principles used in the first one.

I'll let you compute the other derivative :)

Comment: The first derivative is incorrect, $2xy/2xy =1$, you are missing the term $1/5y$.

Comment: @ErikJoensson Thank you ! I edited the post.

Answer (score 0):

### $$f(x,y)=x\frac{\ln(2xy)}{5y}$$

## First Problem $\newcommand{\partialx}{\frac{\partial}{\partial x}} \newcommand{\partialfx}{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}}\newcommand{\partialy}{\frac{\partial}{\partial y}}\newcommand{\partialfy}{\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}}$

Taking a look at the first problem which is $f_{xx}$ examining what that means is that is the same expression as $\frac{\partial^2f(x,y)}{\partial x^2}=\partialx( \partialfx)$. That basically means that first the partial of the function with respect to x, then take that result, and take the partial with respect to x.

\begin{align}f_{xx}&= \partialx \partialfx \\&=\partialx(\frac{\ln(2xy)+1}{5y})\\ f_{xx}&=\frac{1}{5xy}\end{align}

## Second Problem

Then the next part would be in seeing that $f_{xy}=\partialy\partialfx$ Taking the partial of the left most variable first then the right most variable. So to proceed to this problem we would first take the first partial with respect to x first then using that result get the first partial with respect to y of that result.

\begin{align}f_{xy}&=\partialy \partialfx\\ &=\partialy(\frac{\ln(2xy)+1}{5y})\\f_{xy}&=-\frac{\ln(2xy)}{5y^2} \end{align}

## The Third Problem

As you can see the patterns already developing then $f_{yy}=\partialy \partialfy$

\begin{align}f_{yy}&=\partialy \partialfy\\&=\partialy(\frac{x}5(\frac{1-\ln(2xy)}{y^2})) \\f_{yy}&=-\frac{x\left(-2\ln \left(2xy\right)+3\right)}{5y^3}\end{align}